# How i can utilize S(*)(int)?

Tags: c++

For educational reasons, I'm studying the C++ language using clang-12 std=c++17

And I have the following code:

**Fullcode**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

struct S {
  void operator()(int) {}
};

int main()
{
  S(*d)(int); 

  //d = whatValue??

  return 0;
}
```

I'm studying the types of variables that exist in the C++ language, and I came across this situation above.

What value can I assign to the `d` variable?

Could it be a language bug? I've already researched several topics on stackoverflow and cppreference and haven't found any way to initialize this variable `S(*d)(int)` .

Comment: d is a pointer to a function that has the return type S and one parameter of the type int.

Comment: Add a function `S fun(int) { return S{}; }` then you can `d = fun`; or you can do `d = [](int){ return S{}; };` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/o79n3hdvx

Comment: [Pointers to functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions)

Comment: Given that you declared `S::operator()`, also consider this: `void(S::*d)(int); d = &S::operator();`.

Comment: This declaration has nothing to do whatsoever with the overloaded `()` operator of this class, so showing its declaration is irrelevant. If you believe that they're related in some way can you explain a little bit more exactly what you believe the relationship might be, and what this has to do with assigning something to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `d` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` as argument and returning an `S`. Note that it cannot point to non-`static` member functions. You could, e.g., use it like this:

```
struct S {
    void operator()(int) {}
};

S f(int) { return S(); }

int main()
{
    S(*d)(int) = &f;
    S rc = d(17);
}
```

As functions decay to pointer types, you can actually leave the `&` out. The same isn't true for non-`static` member functions, though. If you wanted to get a pointer to a member function of `S` taking an `int` as argument and returning `void` (your `operator()` returns `void` not `S`) you'd need to use the `&`:

```
int main() {
    void (S::*d)(int) = &S::operator();
    S obj;
    S rc = (obj.*d)(17); // use d
}
```

Pointer to member functions are different to pointer to functions because they have an implicit first argument: the `this` pointer. With C++ it is quite rare that pointer to functions are used for other reasons than interfacing C code: using `std::function<void(int)>` is more flexible, although also type-erase and most likely involving a `virtual` function call and not being inlinable. If the function can be a function template it is common to pass function objects which are `std::invoke()`ed (instead of directly called) which support function pointers, pointer to member functions, pointer to non-function members, lambdas, functions, etc.

Comment: In first example, it should read `d(17)` otherwise what is the point to declare such pointer?

Answer (score 4):

> What value can I assign to the d variable?

`d` is a pointer to function, and as such you can assign a function that returns `S` and accepts `int` as a parameter. Example:

```
S some_function(int);
d = some_function;
```

> Could it be a language bug?

No.